# FreeType Extension in PHP

Tags: php, linux, freetype

I have a Linux Shared Hosting on a server that FreeType is not installed on that. But I need to use this extension(imagettftext) for writing texts on images with a specific font.
Now admin of this server said that can't installed that.

So What can I do now??????

Would you please explain about dl function in PHP(Where to put extension and how to use)?

Please Answer A.S.A.P.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `dl` won't solve your problem. You're better off finding a host which supports FreeType. I highly recommend [Dreamhost](http://www.dreamhost.com).

Answer (score 3):

If the admin won't allow you install it, then most likely you're not going to be able to (or even allowed to) load it via `dl()` either.

In other words, if someone says "don't go in that room", then just don't go into that room. Otherwise you're likely to be eaten by a grue.

Comment: usually the .dll/.so goes into PHP's extension directory. However, consider the fact that if you're not allowed to install extensions, trying to do so could get your service terminated.